# Attempting to do a T test with Rcpp using Boost: "No member named" errors

Tags: c++, r, qt, boost, rcpp

I am trying to make some statistical calculations in R faster by using Rcpp. First, I wrote the code in R. Then I wrote the code in C++ using Qt Creator, which required me to use the Boost package. Now, when I try to use `sourceCpp()` to compile a simple function that uses `boost::math::statistics::two_sample_t_test()`, I get
[two errors--click here to see how it looks in RStudio.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eV7EY.png)

> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/BH/include/boost/compute/algorithm/random_shuffle.hpp
> no member named 'random_shuffle' in namespace 'std'; did you mean simply 'random_shuffle'?

> ~/Documents/Research/P-value correction project/Perm FDR with C++ using Rcpp/PermFDR_R/Rcpp.cpp
> no member named 'two_sample_t_test' in namespace 'boost::math::statistics'

[Here is a screenshot of the code in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/BH/include/boost/compute/algorithm/random_shuffle.hpp that pops up when this happens.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRKgW.png)

Here is the R code.

```
library(Rcpp)
library(rstudioapi)
library(BH)

Sys.setenv("PKG_CXXFLAGS"="-std=c++17")
sourceCpp("Rcpp.cpp")
```

Here is the C++ code.

```
//[[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <boost/math/statistics/t_test.hpp>
#include <boost/math/distributions/students_t.hpp>
#include <boost/math/tools/univariate_statistics.hpp>
#include <boost/compute/algorithm/random_shuffle.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/stats.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/mean.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <numeric>
#include <random>

//[[Rcpp::plugins(cpp17)]]

using namespace std;
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

/*
 * Performs a T test on the measurements according to the design (1s and 2s)
 * and returns a P value.
 */
double designTTest(vector<double> ints, vector<int> design) {
  if (ints.size() != design.size()) {
    cout << "ERROR: DESIGN VECTOR AND MEASUREMENT VECTOR NOT EQUAL IN LENGTH!";
    throw;
  }
  
  vector<double> cIntensities;
  vector<double> tIntensities;
  
  for (int i = 0; i < design.size(); i++) {
    if (design[i] == 1) {
      cIntensities.push_back(ints[i]);
    } else if (design[i] == 2) {
      tIntensities.push_back(ints[i]);
    } else {
      cout << "ERROR: DESIGN SYMBOL IS NOT 1 OR 2!";
      throw;
    }
  }
  
  auto [t, p] = boost::math::statistics::two_sample_t_test(cIntensities, tIntensities);
  return p;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double ttestC(NumericVector ints, NumericVector design) {
  vector<double> intVec = as<std::vector<double>>(ints);
  vector<int> designVec = as<std::vector<int>>(design);
  return designTTest(intVec, designVec);
}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Please always include _full output_ from the compiler (and as copy-pasted text, not in images). One of the messages I get while trying to reproduce the issue is `/usr/include/boost/math/tools/univariate_statistics.hpp:15:1: note: ‘#pragma message: This header is deprecated. Use <boost/math/statistics/univariate_statistics.hpp> instead.’
`. Following that advice gets rid of the `random_shuffle` error. Also `two_sample_t_test` has only been added with Boost 1.76, see https://github.com/boostorg/math/pull/487. So your version might simply be too old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot going on in your question, and I am not sure I understand all of (the 'design sorting' is very unclear).

I can, however, help you with the mechanics of `Rcpp`, and use of `Boost` via `BH`. I can suggest a number of changes:

- you do not need to specify either C++11 or C++17; R already defaults to C++14 (if the compiler supports it) under recent version (Edit: We re-add C++17 to ensure structured bindings work)
- you do not need all those headers: we need *one* for `Rcpp`, and *one* for `Boost`
- I recommend against `using namespace ...` and suggest explicit naming
- you do not need a wrapper from R vectors to `std::vector<...>` as `Rcpp` does that for you
- I simplified the error reporting via `Rcpp::stop()`

With all that, plus a mini-demo to run the function, your code becomes simpler and short.

#### Code

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp17)]]

#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <boost/math/statistics/t_test.hpp>

// Performs a T test on the measurements according to the design (1s and 2s)
// and returns a P value.
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double designTTest(std::vector<double> ints, std::vector<double> design) {
    if (ints.size() != design.size()) Rcpp::stop("ERROR: DESIGN VECTOR AND MEASUREMENT VECTOR NOT EQUAL IN LENGTH!");
    std::vector<double> cIntensities, tIntensities;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < design.size(); i++) {
        if (design[i] == 1) {
            cIntensities.push_back(ints[i]);
        } else if (design[i] == 2) {
            tIntensities.push_back(ints[i]);
        } else {
            Rcpp::stop("ERROR: DESIGN SYMBOL IS NOT 1 OR 2!");
        }
    }

    auto [t, p] = boost::math::statistics::two_sample_t_test(cIntensities, tIntensities);
    return p;
}

/*** R
designTTest(c(1,2,1,2,1), c(2,1,2,1,2))
*/
```

We can source this for compilation *and* the example (with possibly non-sensical data).

#### Output

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/72652032/answer.cpp")

> designTTest(c(1,2,1,2,1), c(2,1,2,1,2))
[1] 0
>
```

I removed a bunch of compilation noise that goes away when you add `-Wno-parentheses` to your `CXXFLAGS` in `~/.R/Makevars`. CRAN does not let me (as `BH` maintainer) keep th upstream `#pragmas` so noisy it is ...

Comment: The structured binding should not compile with C++14-only, which is probably why OP added C++17 in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I realized that later too.  R 4.2.0 sets it to C++17 anyway, but we can also (re-)add the Rcpp tag to enforce it.

Comment: Thank you, Dirk! Unfortunately when I try to source your version, I get the following error. This is pasted from the compiler output.

Comment: Rcpp.cpp:26:42: error: no member named 'two_sample_t_test' in namespace 'boost::math::statistics'
  auto [t, p] = boost::math::statistics::two_sample_t_test(cIntensities, tIntensities);
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^

Comment: I answered the question with a version that worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04; you have access to it at this URL:  https://github.com/eddelbuettel/stackoverflow/blob/master/72652032/answer.cpp - good luck.

Comment: Hi Dirk, I reinstalled the BH package hoping that this was a version issue, and that fixed it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the full compiler output boost is telling you that you are not supposed to include `<boost/math/tools/univariate_statistics.hpp>`. You are supposed to include `<boost/math/statistics/univariate_statistics.hpp>` instead:

```
/usr/include/boost/math/tools/univariate_statistics.hpp:15:1: note: ‘#pragma message: This header is deprecated. Use <boost/math/statistics/univariate_statistics.hpp> instead.’
```

Following that advice, I don't get the `std::random_shuffle` error message anymore.

---

The other error message regarding `two_sample_t_test` is probably because that was added only relatively recently to boost, with version 1.76, see https://github.com/boostorg/math/pull/487. You might be using an older version.